# Dimension of the span of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am sorry for quite a silly question.
What is the dimension of the span of $2$ linearly dependent vectors over $\mathbb{R}^3$.
For example, I have $v=(1, 2, 1)$ and $u=(2, 4, 2)$.

Comment: If both vectors are the 0 vector, they are linearly dependent but their span is{[0,0,0]} whose dimension is 0.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Isn't the answer $1$ instead?

Comment: What is your definition of the dimension of a vector space?

Answer (score 2):

The span has dimension 2 if and only if your vectors are not  one multiple of the other.

In the case you prpposed  $(2,4,2)=2\cdot(1,2,1)$ and the span has dimension 1.

Comment: I am really confused. I got 3 different answers from 3 different people (0, 1, 2) for the dimension

Comment: Much better the four answer from three people ...  But wait, that can't happen for dimensional reasons.  Nevertheless, the answer is ONE.  Final answer.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For a finite dimensional vector space, the dimension is the number of elements in a basis (any basis will have the same number of elements)

The span of vectors forms a subspace (and so is a vector space).

So, $v$ and $u$ span a subspace, but are not linearly independent so are not a basis for that subspace.

$v$ will also span your space, and $\{v\}$ is independent, so $\textbf{in your example}$ the answer should be 1.

A commenter was making the point that $\{0, 0\}$ is a linearly dependent set of two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has dimension $0$, because the zero subspace is defined to have dimension $0$ (and is the only vector space of dimension $0$)

So, in summary, the subspace spanned by two linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will have dimension $1$ unless they both happen to be the zero vector in which case the space has dimension $0$